# Vue.js and Vuetify: Call method when clicking an item

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm new to javascript and Vue.js. I am trying to switch `vue-bootstrap` to `vuetify`.
What I want to do is to call a method when clicking a dropdown item.

My previous code using `vue-bootstrap` is like this.

```
<! -- This part is inside for loop -->
<b-dropdown variant="transparent">
    <b-dropdown-item @click="aMethod(index, 'Hello')">A</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item @click="aMethod(index, 'Bye')">B</b-dropdown-item>
</b-dropdown>
```

And now I want to do this using vuetify but how can I call method?

```
<v-overflow-btn label="A" :items="aList" />

...
aList: [{text: 'A'},{text: 'B'}]
```

I want to pass the index as a parameter to the method.

Also how can I make the default label the same looking as the items like dropdown in bootstrap does?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `@change` event on you button:

```js
<v-overflow-btn label="A" :items="aList" @change="aMethod(arg1, arg2, etc...)" />
```

Comment: How can I pass different parameter depending on the item?